# I need query to exclude a particular alphanumeric pattern in Oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a column with value

```
String = 'Select Id,name,model_1,model_2,model_30 from employee'
```

I need the output to exclude ',model%'
i.e o/p should be

```
'Select Id,name from employee'
```

I used `regexp_replace(string,[',model'+\d])`, but this is returning numbers as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your string is exactly in the form you showed, you have only some syntax issues; you need:

```
regexp_replace(yourString, ',model_\d+', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace `,model_[numbers]`. You can use `regexp_replace` as follows:

```
regexp_replace(your_string, '(,model_[0-9]+)','')
```

[Db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e62bb5c96ff195569ccd0faba0b26440)